# PHP include not working from other directory

Tags: php, include, ini

I have a small PHP application that works fine on many hosting accounts and on my local server.

I'm trying to set it up for a client but the includes don't seem to work. If I am inside the application directory, all includes work fine but if I try include a file from inside this  directory into a file that is located outside of this directory, it is not included. I get no errors. The php file is just not included.

I have the very same setup on other accounts and everything works fine. I am thinking that it may be some security permission settings or php.ini configuration issue.

Since I don't get any error, I don't know where to start looking. The include look like this:

```
<?php require_once('foldername/foldername/filename.php');?>
```

How can I start investigating where the problem is?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is safe mode on in the site that doesn't work?  Additionally, what does `open_basedir` look like?

Comment: maybe your hosting is configurated to not show errors. You can try activating this using this line in the first line of your PHP file: ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: Are you reporting or/and logging errors? Perhaps you can check your error log or temporarily set `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. That line indicates that you are expecting something to be in your include path that may not be there, but I would assume you know that. Still, see what the include path is where you are trying  to include the filename.php `echo get_include_path();`.

Comment: Does this work if you path it using a path from the document root?

Comment: @K.G. Yes, safe mode is turned on. Could that be causing the include problem?

Comment: If `safe_mode` is enabled, then the owner of the file doing the including and the file included have to be the same.  If you've uploaded both, this isn't likely a problem, but one more thing to check.  More important is `open_basedir`.  Whether or not `safe_mode` is on, if `open_basedir` is set, only files from that directory can be included.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your [`include_path`](http://bd.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) is not proper. Make sure

1. `.` is in your include_path
2. If `foldername/foldername/filename.php` is in `/path/to/project` directory so it forms `/path/to/project/foldername/foldername/filename.php`, put `/path/to/project` in your path.